# Importing multiple product prices/currencies in Magento using Magento 1.5/EE

Tags: magento

I'm importing simple Magento products using the new import-export module in Magento 1.5+ with different prices for different websites (1 site is £29 another is 34 euros).  When I run the import though the price for all sites is set as 34 (pounds or euros depending).

Has anybody successfully imported product prices to multiple sites/views from the same file?

Does anybody have an example CSV file that is successfully importing a UK price to one store and a different Euro price to another?

Living in hope.

S

Answer (score 0):

You can create an example file yourself. Just create a sample product in the backend and export it to a csv - you should get the csv definition. The trick is to add separate lines to your csv for different values in different websites. Vinai Kopp made a nice presentation which might be helpful: http://netzarbeiter.com/media/MagentoImagine/ImportExport.pdf

Comment: Yep - I'd already done all that.  The problem is that when you reimport it, it doesn't respect the set website for the price import.  It sets the price for all stores to the value of the first line for that product.

Comment: in the generated export file, is the website defined as a string or as an id? - you probably need to define the id in the import, but the export contains the name?